# changing the colour of symbols in sclass plot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to create a plot displaying two variables, with groupings (ellipses) for one and symbols coloured for the other. "RW1" on the x axis, "RW2" on the y axis, grouping ellipses according to "Morph.cluster" and colouring the geometric shapes according to "ALL", which is the genetic cluster. I'm using ade4 in the adegenet package for this. The issue is that I can only seem to get the plot working for one variable at a time.

My data looks like

```
ID  ggpop   AC70    AC50    ALL Morph.cluster   RW1 RW2 RW3
LT-103  gg3 NA  2   2   1   0.00793 0.01137 -0.00379
LT-109  gg4 1   1   1   2   -0.0156 -0.01056    0.00869
LT-110  gg3 1   1   1   1   0.01585 0.00077 -0.00923
LT-12   gg5 4   4   4   1   0.01299 0.00383 0.00517
LT-122  gg4 NA  3   3   1   0.02727 0.01845 -0.0078
```

For some samples ggpop is NA. For these samples I hope that I I can just leave the colour empty. If not, I'll just make another gg category and label these ones as empty.

Using

```
library(ade4)
plot_All = plot(RWggclust2_eds$RW1,RWggclust2_eds$RW2, type="n", yaxt="n", 
                ylab="RW2 (17%)", xlab="RW1 (26%)")
axis(2, las=2)
myCol2=transp(c('#7F7F7FFF', '#D99694FF', '#00B0F0FF', '#00B050FF', '#000000FF'), 0.6)
abline(h=0,v=0,col="grey", lty=2)
s.class(cbind(RWggclust2_eds$RW1, RWggclust2_eds$RW2), 
        fac=as.factor(RWggclust2_eds$Morph.cluster), 
        add.plot=T, 
        col=myCol2,
        cpoint=2,
        clabel=0,
        pch=c(15,16,17) [as.numeric(RWggclust2_eds$Morph.cluster)],
        axesell=F,
        addaxes=F,
        cstar=0,
        cellipse = 1.5)
```

[image: plot of first code]

I get the above with the ellipses drawn the way that I want, defining the morphological clusters, but the colours of the geometric shapes are not what I am looking for. I would like the colours to be according to the five groups defined in “ALL”, which are the genetic clusters.

However, using

```
RWggclust2_eds <- read.csv("RWggclust2_eds.csv")
str(RWggclust2_eds)
RWggclust2_eds$ALL = as.factor(RWggclust2_eds$ALL)
RWggclust2_eds$ALL = as.factor(RWggclust2_eds$ggpop)
RWggclust2_eds$Morph.cluster = as.factor(RWggclust2_eds$Morph.cluster)

plot_All = plot(RWggclust2_eds$RW1,RWggclust2_eds$RW2, type="n", yaxt="n", 
                ylab="RW2 (17%)", xlab="RW1 (26%)")
axis(2, las=2)

myCol2=transp(c('#7F7F7FFF', '#D99694FF', '#00B0F0FF', '#00B050FF', '#000000FF'), 0.6)
abline(h=0,v=0,col="grey", lty=2)
s.class(cbind(RWggclust2_eds$RW1, RWggclust2_eds$RW2), 
        fac=as.factor(RWggclust2_eds$ALL), 
        add.plot=T, 
        col=myCol2,
        cpoint=2,
        clabel=0,
        pch=c(15,16,17) [as.numeric(RWggclust2_eds$Morph.cluster)],
        axesell=F,
        addaxes=F,
        cstar=0,
        cellipse = 1.5)
```

[image: plot with second try]

I get the above, with ellipses drawn on the genetic clusters (the “ALL” column in my dataset), which is not what I want (I want the shapes to be grouped according to my first plot), but the colours in the plot are correct.

I've tired all sorts of iterations of the "col" argument as well

```
#index=as.integer(RWggclust2_eds$ALL)
#sclasscolour=rainbow(6)
#sclasscolour=transp(c('#7F7F7FFF', '#D99694FF', '#00B0F0FF', '#00B050FF', '#000000FF'), 0.6)
#myCol2= transp(c(sclasscolour), 1) [index]
```

The issue is I think that the colour of symbols is being read from "fac", but is seems like the distrubtion of Morph.cluster is as well.

I would be glad to post my datafile if there is a way to do so.

Comment: @StupidWolf, do you have any suggestions for additional tags that I can add to get a response?

Comment: Hi Ella! sorry I wanted to take a look at this but it slipped my mind. If RWggclust2_eds is not too big, can you dput(RWggclust2_eds) and paste it in your post? Otherwise share a link with me in the comment?

Comment: And I think for tags, maybe bioinformatics and others?

Comment: @StupidWolf, what email address should I use to send a link to the file? It's not super huge, but I think it will be easier to work with that way.

Comment: For some reason I am not finding the button to insert links to files. I'm pretty much 100% sure that it's just my "col" argument that is off. I need to somehow use the groupings in the "ALL" column to define the colours used to fill the shapes

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202417/ellabowles-sclass ; see whether you can access the chatroom? I messaged my email address

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf. Just in case you don't check email regularly, I sent it a couple hrs ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. I think in s.class, the color of the points will go together with the eclipse (at least as far as I have tried).

Since you had to layer the eclipse onto an empty plot, I think the easiest solution is to first plot the points according to what you like, then add on the eclipses without the points (setting pch=NA)

I used alpha from ggplot for the transparency but feel free to change it back

```
library(ade4)
library(ggplot2)
# i use alpha from ggplot2
# how i read and proceeded with your csv file
#CSV = read.csv("RWggclust2_eds.csv")
#RWggclust2_eds = CSV[,c("ggpop","ALL","Morph.cluster","RW1","RW2")]

# similar to what you did
# just providing names
myCol2=alpha(c('#7F7F7FFF', '#D99694FF', '#00B0F0FF', '#00B050FF', '#000000FF'), 0.6)
# set it according to popn
names(myCol2) = levels(RWggclust2_eds$ggpop)
# set the shapes
PCH = c(15,16,17)

# we can wrap it around using with
plot_All = with(RWggclust2_eds,
           plot(RW1,RW2, yaxt="n", 
                ylab="RW2 (17%)", xlab="RW1 (26%)",
                pch= PCH[Morph.cluster],
                col=myCol2[as.character(ggpop)]
           )
)
#provide a legend 
legend("topleft",names(myCol2),fill=myCol2,horiz=T,cex=0.7)

axis(2, las=2)
abline(h=0,v=0,col="grey", lty=2)

s.class(cbind(RWggclust2_eds$RW1, RWggclust2_eds$RW2), 
        fac=as.factor(RWggclust2_eds$Morph.cluster), 
        add.plot=T, 
        cpoint=2,
        clabel=0,
        pch=NA,
        axesell=F,
        addaxes=F,
        cstar=0,
        cellipse = 1.5)
```

You get the plot:

[image]

Below is the data for making the plot

```
dput(RWggclust2_eds)
    structure(list(ggpop = structure(c(3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), .Label = c("gg1", "gg2", "gg3", "gg4", "gg5"), class = "factor"), 
        ALL = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
        3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
        1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
        1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
        3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
        1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
        5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
        1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
        5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
        3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
        1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
        1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Morph.cluster = c(1L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
        2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
        1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
        1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
        3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), RW1 = c(0.00793, 
        -0.0156, 0.01585, 0.01299, 0.02727, 0.00344, 0.031, 0.01568, 
        -0.00411, -0.00076, 0.01339, 0.02017, 0.02123, -0.0061, 0.01376, 
        -0.02301, 0.00501, 0.02418, -0.00102, -0.00813, 0.0032, -0.0122, 
        -0.00317, 0.00018, 0.00051, -0.00184, -0.00323, 0.01701, 
        -0.00027, 0.00288, -0.00689, -0.01864, 0.003, 0.00463, 0.0119, 
        -0.01515, 0.00364, 0.02048, -0.01233, -0.00774, -0.00348, 
        -0.00219, 0.00676, -0.00978, 0.00767, -0.00819, -0.01892, 
        -0.00584, 0.012, 0.00617, -0.01743, -0.02724, -0.03363, 0.01004, 
        0.02196, 0.01074, 0.0053, 0.00197, -0.01368, 0.00802, -0.00659, 
        -0.00521, -0.00938, 0.00901, 0.00639, 0.02151, -0.01637, 
        -0.02571, -0.00354, -0.00396, 0.03228, 0.01599, -0.00646, 
        0.00993, 0.02582, -0.01889, 0.01162, 0.00487, 0.02127, -0.00994, 
        -0.01862, 0.01338, 0.00229, 0.01818, 0.00687, 0.00545, 0.01723, 
        0.00438, 0.00832, 0.00095, -0.00751, -0.00645, -0.01469, 
        -0.01141, 0.01079, -0.00567, 0.00348, 0.00904, 0.00055, 0.02002, 
        -0.00382, -0.00244, 0.03351, -0.01225, 0.00865, -0.00105, 
        -0.01337, 0.00853, -0.00584, -0.001, -0.00068, -0.01427, 
        0.00742, 0.00352, -0.01016, -0.00713, -0.00129, -0.01557, 
        -0.00792, -0.00067, 0.00432, -0.01509, 0.03477, 0.01061, 
        -0.00097, 0.00797, -0.01066, -0.01534, 0.0192, 0.00266, -0.00549, 
        -0.02314, 0.00139, -0.02194, -0.00406, 0.00287, -0.01561, 
        -0.00329, 0.01625, 0.00822, 0.01719, -0.00545, 0.0019, 0.00278, 
        0.00436, 0.01424, -0.01102, -0.01331, 0.00928, 0.01181, 0.00416, 
        0.01673, 0.00715, -0.0159, -0.00208, -0.03367, 9e-04, -0.00011, 
        -0.02768, -0.01608, -0.00345, 0.00062, 0.00048, -0.01542, 
        0.02665, -0.0181, 0.0098, -0.00995, 0.00842, 0.00123, 0.00896, 
        0.02197, -0.00163, -0.01072, -0.01137, -0.01126, -0.01656, 
        0.00518, 0.03913, -0.02236, -0.02881, -0.0117, 0.01644, -0.00465, 
        -0.00811, 0.00107, 0.02483, 0.00197, -0.01018, 0.01023, 0.01279, 
        -0.01052, -0.0069, -0.01409, 0.01462, 0.00435, 0.01912, -0.01392, 
        0.02166, 0.00621, 0.0112, -0.01114, 0.00728, -0.0086, 5e-05, 
        0.00352, -0.00939, -0.01502, 0.00394, 0.01684, -0.00077, 
        -0.00037, 0.00563, -0.03636, 0.00443, 0.01819, 0.00603, -0.00363, 
        -0.02126, 0.01857, 0.00014, -0.03048, 0.00621, -0.00452, 
        0.02451, 0.00715, -0.00705, 0.01619, -0.016, -0.00362, -0.00949, 
        0.02046, -0.016, -0.01655, 0.00079, 0.00188, -0.01497, 0.01269, 
        0.02089, -0.01006, -0.01574, -0.00349, -0.01533, 0.01438, 
        0.0055, -0.00257, 0.00254, -0.00647, -0.00356, 0.02158, -0.03029, 
        0.01802, -0.00391, -0.01141, -0.0355, 0.00911, 0.00136, 0.00631, 
        -0.00551, -0.01403, 0.00929, 0.0059, -0.00238, 0.00028, -0.01683, 
        0.00347, -0.0213, 0.00411, 0.00953, 0.00029, -0.0028, 0.01801, 
        0.00405, -0.0079, -0.01496, -0.00638, -0.01092, -0.00773, 
        -0.00368, 0.00526, -0.00739), RW2 = c(0.01137, -0.01056, 
        0.00077, 0.00383, 0.01845, 0.00058, 0.02422, 0.00129, -0.01173, 
        -0.0161, 0.01019, 0.00135, 0.00579, 0.00576, 0.00751, 0.01384, 
        0.00408, -0.00634, -0.00044, -0.00168, -0.00021, 0.00019, 
        0.00428, -0.00924, 0.00098, 0.00518, -0.00184, -0.00469, 
        -0.00921, -3e-05, 0.00688, -0.00778, 0.00165, -0.00664, 0.00856, 
        -0.00157, 0.00322, -7e-05, -0.00405, 6e-04, -0.00464, -0.0019, 
        -0.00849, 0.00363, -0.01107, 0.00175, -0.03478, -0.00816, 
        -0.00338, 0.02075, -0.00039, -0.02465, -0.01461, 0.00529, 
        -0.00144, -0.00259, -0.00803, -0.00693, 0.00761, 0.01159, 
        0.01422, -0.00876, -0.00469, -0.00052, 0.00823, 0.01019, 
        0.00032, 0.00842, 0.02197, 4e-04, -0.02939, 0.00432, 0.00774, 
        0.00848, -0.00342, -0.00953, -0.01048, -0.0014, -0.01465, 
        0.0027, 0.00879, -4e-05, 0.00985, -0.03324, 0.01427, 0.00036, 
        -0.01587, -0.0012, 0.00331, 0.0089, -0.00684, -0.0348, 0.00497, 
        0.01468, -0.00218, -0.01662, 0.00608, -0.01143, 0.00312, 
        -0.01165, 0.00966, 0.00179, -0.01137, 0.00335, 0.0152, -0.00442, 
        0.01031, -0.01745, -0.01658, 0.003, 0.011, -0.00583, 0.0171, 
        0.00062, 0.00842, 0.00759, -0.00401, 0.01916, -0.00491, 0.01416, 
        0.00117, -0.00164, -0.02815, 0.00648, 0.00067, -0.006, -0.00454, 
        0.00368, 0.00666, 0.00352, 0.00368, -0.00999, 0.01213, -0.0022, 
        -0.0015, -0.02383, 0.00748, -4e-05, -0.02224, -0.01355, 0.00525, 
        0.00142, 0.01344, 0.00639, 0.00822, 0.01765, 0.00431, -0.0019, 
        0.00204, 0.03139, 0.00251, -0.00123, -0.00833, -0.01289, 
        0.00716, 0.00198, 0.00263, 0.00632, 0.00179, -5e-05, 0.0088, 
        -0.0017, -0.00574, 0.00356, -0.02567, 0.00984, 0.00209, 0.0072, 
        0.00377, -0.0085, 0.01386, 0.00746, 0.00415, -0.01666, 0.00516, 
        0.00883, -0.01979, 0.01931, 0.00208, 0.00411, 0.01303, -0.00108, 
        0.00854, -0.00262, -0.02486, 0.0179, -0.00035, 0.01651, 0.00952, 
        0.00668, -0.00279, 0.00344, 0.00314, -0.00599, 0.00954, -0.02629, 
        -0.00226, 0.00282, 0.00765, 0.00624, -0.00497, -0.00269, 
        0.01129, -0.02122, 0.00841, -0.0011, -0.00747, 0.01913, -0.0024, 
        0.01528, -0.00184, -0.005, -0.01863, 0.02115, -0.00814, 0.01531, 
        0.00641, -0.00111, -0.01767, 0.01528, -0.00414, -0.01503, 
        -0.00082, 0.00429, 0.00032, 0.01733, -0.00656, 0.00176, -0.00597, 
        0.00423, -0.00541, 0.01085, -0.00327, -4e-04, 0.01826, -0.00852, 
        0.0098, -0.01052, 0.0188, 0.00234, -0.00113, -0.00335, -0.01121, 
        -0.00305, 0.0065, -0.0032, -0.00877, -0.01151, -0.01051, 
        -0.00295, 0.00751, -0.00828, -0.00164, -0.00109, 0.01665, 
        0.01285, -0.00875, -0.01182, -0.01427, 0.01631, -0.00241, 
        -0.0055, 0.00393, 0.00351, 0.00061, -0.00063, 0.01053, -0.00094, 
        0.00509, 0.00162, 0.00295, -0.00789, -0.03162, 0.00523, -0.00361, 
        -0.00171, -0.00459, 0.00237, -0.03454, -0.01103, 0.00944)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -281L))
```